# Xamarin.UWP and Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, xamarin.forms, firebase-analytics, xamarin.uwp

I am looking how to implement Google Analytics with Xamarin.UWP project specifically.
After spending some time researching I find that Google Analytics now requires you to use Firebase, but Firebase supports only Android, iOS, and Web but not UWP.

I have found two Nugget packages that seem to support this:

**1. UWP.SDKforGoogleAnalytics**

**2. ksemenenko.GoogleAnalytics**

Has anyone implemented these with Xamarin.UWP projects successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to give a try to both.  While I was unsuccessful in using **UWP.SDKforGoogleAnalytics**, implementation of **ksemenenko.GoogleAnalytics** was quite smooth